# BibTex bibliography style for MHRA (Modern Humanities Research Association)

Tags: bibtex

is anyone aware of a Bibtex `bibliographystyle` for MHRA (Modern Humanities Research Association) system? Or otherwise know how I would go about creating my own reference style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't know any, but you can take a look at `biblatex-dw`, which defines humanities styles for biblatex.

Comment: The menu-driven `makebst` utility, part of the `custom-bib` package, lets users create bespoke bst files. Open a command window and type `pdflatex makebst` to get started.